# Months with year for each bar in Dual Y axis plot: geom_bar, geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a date variable in my data frame and two other variables. I wish to create a dual Y-axis plot with two variables, one with bar and one with line. I have successfully done that.
There are some other problems:

1. I am not getting month and year for each bar. I am getting some month name only. I wish I have Nov-20, Dec-20, Jan-21 etc below each bar.
2. Axis titles are not in the middle of the axis.
3. Legends are not showing.
   Any help with the above 3 problems is appreciated.
   Here is my code:

```
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(hrbrthemes)

# Build dummy data
data <- data.frame(
  day = as.Date(c("2020-11-01", "2020-12-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01",
                  "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", "2021-05-01")),
  var1 = runif(7, 150, 200),
  var2 = runif(7, 6, 20)
)

# Value used to transform the data
coeff <- max(data$var1)/max(data$var2)

# A few constants
var1Color <- "#69b3a2"
var2Color <- rgb(0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=day)) +
  
  geom_bar( aes(y=var1), stat="identity", size=.1, 
            fill=var1Color, color="black", alpha=.4, width = 7) + 
  
  geom_line( aes(y=var2 * coeff), size=2, color = var2Color) +
  
  scale_y_continuous(
    
    # Features of the first axis
    name = "Variable 1",
    
    # Add a second axis and specify its features
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./coeff, name ="Variable 2")
  ) + 
  
  theme_ipsum() +
  
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = var1Color, size=13),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = var2Color, size=13)
  ) +
  
  xlab("Month")

p
```

Here is the plot I have got.

[Dual Y-axis Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5gCn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem can be solved using:

```
library(lubridate)

p + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%d", breaks = seq(as.Date(min(data$day)), as.Date(max(data$day)), by = "month"))
```

[image]

Problem 2 does not show up for me when running your code without using `theme_ipsum` (see figure).

**UPDATE:**

To add a legend containing your desired content you have to define both `fill = var1Color` and `color = var2Color` as arguments of `aes` (to generate the legend entries) as well as use `scale_fill_manual()` and `scale_color_manual()` to use your defined colors:

```
  geom_bar(aes(y = var1, fill = var1Color), stat = "identity", size = .1, 
             color = "black", alpha = .4, width = 7) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = var2 * coeff, color = var2Color), size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = var1Color) +
  scale_color_manual(values = var2Color)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was hoping to get legend with shape and color of both plot types.

Comment: Modified my answer to show your desired legend.